# Strange php setcookie

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I'm having a strange problem of php setcookie.
Let me show the code

```
setcookie('aaa', 'aaa', time()+100);  // aaa cookie can be set
if($_POST){
    setcookie('bbb', 'bbb', time()+100);   // bbb cookie can't be set
    echo 'bbb';
}
```

aaa cookie can be set. But bbb cookie can't be set.
I'm 100% sure that the if condition is true and bbb is echo.

This is the real code.
But the most strange thing is that 'bbb' cookie can be set sometimes.
So I think there's some configuration problem.

I'm running Apache(2.2.20) and PHP(5.3.6)

**EDIT：

I'm running this page in iframe in the same domain and same directory.**

Comment: it mean that the condition of if is false

Comment: Sorry. Let me edit the problem. I'm 100% sure that the condition is true.

Comment: `if($_POST)` is always true. You need to check `if($_POST['your_key'])`. Now, do not take `your_key` literary.

Comment: Can you write to the log or the page when you attempt to set the bbb cookie, so you can be 110% sure the attempt is being made and failing?

Comment: @Magic What makes you 100% certain that the `if` condition is true?  Please give us some extra info. eg: "I am 100% sure that the if condition is true, because ..."

Comment: I've edit the code and echo 'bbb'. It has echo the 'bbb'. So I'm pretty sure the condition is true.

Comment: can you `var_dump` your `$_COOKIE`? I tried your code and didn't seen anything wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you have problems setting a cookie it's because the `headers` were already sent before you did `setcookie`. When you're in the `if` condition, do

```
if(headers_sent()) 
    throw new Exception('Headers were already sent!!!');
```

If you get an exception, then your headers are being send before you set the cookie, thus your cookie doesn't get sent to the client's browser.

Answer (score 1):

What are you testing?  That there is a post array or that it has values?  Be explicit in your conditions to reflect exacly what you want.  Use empty(), is_null(), ===, ==, or isset() depending on your need.  I am guessing you really want to make sure values are being posted, so use

```
if(!empty($_POST)){
  // values were posted, do cookie stuff here....
}
```

If you don't care if values are posred or not, but actually just want to know the action was a post use:

```
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
```

Comment: I've edit the problem. My problem is not the if condition. but the setcookie problem.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't set your cookie is that the if:

```
if($_POST){
    setcookie('bbb', 'bbb', time()+100);   // bbb cookie can't be set
}
```

Is returning `false`.

You probably meant:

```
if(isset($_POST['bbb']) && $_POST['bbb'] !="") {
    setcookie('bbb', 'bbb', time()+100);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I've edit the problem.I'm 100% sure that the if condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_POST) { ... }
```

is not a reliable way to detect a POST request distinctly from other request methods.

Instead, you probably want to use something like:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify parameter *path* where the cookie will be saved:

```
setcookie('name', 'value', time()+100, '/');
```

[setcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: That's not necessary - `The default value is the current directory that the cookie is being set in.` (http://php.net/setcookie)

Comment: @tftd: True, but I've had cases where it was necessary to set the cookie worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that the condition is returning false.

The first step to debug is to echo inside the condition.

> if($_POST){    echo "Testing"; }

Also, I would use isset instead of `if($var)` because in your case if `$_POST` is not set, you will generate a notice that you would have to suppress.

There are better and precise ways to get that condition done right. Eg : `isset($var)`,`!isset($var), is_null($var), empty($var)`

ADD :

Since you said the echo works, I would suggest using setcookie with all the basic handles.

> if($_POST){  setcookie('bbb', 'bbb', time()+100, '/','yoursite.com');
>   }

I am not sure if that has to do anything, but try it out. Obviously you need to check before the expiry happens (less than 2 mins)

Comment: @Magic - Updated the answer. Can you check again?

Comment: Try as you suggest. But it's not helpful.